# SQLAlchemy query returns None

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to check, by ID, if some entry is already created in DB by this way:

```
def if_entry_exist(self, uid, table_name, by="id"):

    tb = self.get_table_by_name(table_name)
    #t = self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(tb[0].c[by].key==uid).scalar() 
    #quer = self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(tb[0].c[by].key == uid)
    #print(self.session.query(quer.exists()).scalar())

    #exists = self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(tb[0].c[by].key==uid).scalar() is not None
    return bool(self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(tb[0].c[by].key==uid).first())
```

I tried different types of queries, but it doesn't result. It always return false or None when I confirm that the IDs are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing the key of the [`Column`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) with the `uid`, not the column itself. The key is `"id"`, or what `by` happens to be in a call, so `...key == uid` is very likely going to evaluate to `False` in Python, which means that your query is effectively

```
return bool(self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(False).first())
```

which should make it obvious why the query never returns results. Just remove the key attribute access and perform the comparison with the `Column`:

```
return bool(self.session.query(tb[0]).filter(tb[0].c[by] == uid).first())
```

Comment: Ohh, what a mistake. I tested different ways, and absolutly forgot about this. Thank you so much!